# How to use R to solve/pick the best people for a job - with restraints?

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, solver, maximize, integer-programming

I'm fairly new to R and I'm trying to write a script for what I used to do with Solver in Excel.  In my data below, I have a list of workers with job types A-E.  Each worker has a salary and a production rate.  What I want R to do is find the maximum production I can get from 10 workers with a cumulative salary <100,000.  The restraints are that I need an exact total of 10 workers and I need 2 from job types A-D, 1 from E, and 1 of any type.

I've searched and searched for a way to do this with optim, IpSolve, etc., but with my limited knowledge I have not had much luck.

Thank you for your help!

```
Name    Pos Salary  Producton
Joe     A   12001   13.1
Jim     A   17753   23.5
Jill    A   11447   14.8
Brian   A   11447   14.8
Sally   B   2171    1.2
Nancy   B   4537    2.1
Francis B   2840    1.8
Ace     B   2840    1.8
Bill    C   3818    1.6
Ted     C   11447   0.1
Henry   C   2000    1.1
Kyle    C   3818    1.6
Sam     D   11447   0.1
Trevor  D   2000    1.1
John    D   4317    11.7
Jerome  D   2000    1.1
Rebecca E   3818    1.6
Sunny   E   11447   0.1
Britt   E   2000    1.1
Sara    E   4317    11.7
```

Comment: Yes, a minimum of 2. Thank you!

Comment: Just a thought:  choose(20,10) = 184756, so it won't take all that long to test every possible combination in this small case.  Unless, of course, this is homework and you *must* use a solver.

Comment: Luckily it's not homework, but the full list has over three hundred people in it. My mistake, I should have mentioned that in the original post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `lp` in the lpSolve package to solve the underlying integer programming problem.   The first 5 constraints are on the number of A, B, C, D and E positions respectively, the 6th is on the number of staff to choose and the 7th is on the total salary.  Assuming `DF` is the data frame shown in the question try this:

```
library(lpSolve)

obj <- DF$Prod
con <- rbind(t(model.matrix(~ Pos + 0, DF)), rep(1, nrow(DF)), DF$Salary)
dir <- c(">=", ">=", ">=", ">=", ">=", "==", "<")
rhs <- c(2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 10, 100000)

result <- lp("max", obj, con, dir, rhs, all.bin = TRUE)
```

which gives:

```
> result
Success: the objective function is 84.7 
> DF[result$solution == 1, ]
     Name Pos Salary Producton
2     Jim   A  17753      23.5
3    Jill   A  11447      14.8
4   Brian   A  11447      14.8
6   Nancy   B   4537       2.1
8     Ace   B   2840       1.8
9    Bill   C   3818       1.6
12   Kyle   C   3818       1.6
14 Trevor   D   2000       1.1
15   John   D   4317      11.7
20   Sara   E   4317      11.7
```

Note that Production is misspelled in the question or perhaps that was intended.

ADDED:

Regarding the second best solution the idea is to add a constraint which makes the best solution infeasible but does not exclude other potential solutions:

```
con2 <- rbind(con, result$solution)
dir2 <- c(dir, "<=")
rhs2 <- c(rhs, 9)
result2 <- lp("max", obj, con2, dir2, rhs2, all.bin = TRUE)
```

In this case we get the following which has the same optimum objective value as the best solution so it would be just as good:

```
> result2
Success: the objective function is 84.7 
> DF[result2$solution == 1, ]
     Name Pos Salary Producton
2     Jim   A  17753      23.5
3    Jill   A  11447      14.8
4   Brian   A  11447      14.8
6   Nancy   B   4537       2.1
8     Ace   B   2840       1.8
9    Bill   C   3818       1.6
12   Kyle   C   3818       1.6
15   John   D   4317      11.7
16 Jerome   D   2000       1.1
20   Sara   E   4317      11.7
```

There are also arguments to `lp` which allow it to produce multiple solutions directly; however, the help file mentions some bugs and it may be safer to take the above approach.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much! As icing on the cake, is there a way to get the 2nd best solution?

Comment: Question: I was thinking of an algorithm like: 1) calculate a figure of merit, i.e. Production/Salary, 2)Grab the top FOM candidate from every required category (A-E), 3) fill the remaining slots with the top remaining FOM values.  Is that essentially what `lpSolve` is doing?

Comment: @Derek, Have added a second-best solution.  @Carl, `lp` uses the branch-and-bound algorithm.

Comment: Fantastic! My final question is can we add code to exclude a specific person, say "Jim"? As if he called in sick and was no longer an option.  I know I could delete him from DF, but it would be nice if I could simply change it in the model.  Thanks again!

Comment: Just add a constraint that sets the Jim variable to 0.  That is append this constraint to the constraint matrix `as.numeric(DF$Name == "Jim")`, append this to the direction "==" and append this to the `rhs`: `0` .